# Pointer returning NULL from extern structure in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have defined following global structure in a .h file:

> file1.h

```
struct kobject_saved {
struct kobject* kobject;
}
extern struct kobject_saved *ksaved;
```

> file1.c

```
#include <file1.h>

struct kobject_saved *ksaved = kmalloc(sizeof(struct kobject_saved), GFP_KERNEL);
ksaved->kobject = some_kobject; // some_kobject is a initialized pointer to kobj
```

> file2.c

```
#include <file1.h>

struct kobject *ko = ksaved->kobject;
```

Here, I am getting the value of kobject to be null. Even though the call to file2.c is made after initialization happens at file1.c

Can you please help me to access kobject without losing the data? Possibly point out where I am going wrong?

Many thanks,

Update: This is my exact code for some_object. I am getting correct address for "ko" though..

```
void save_my_kobject(struct kobject *ko)
{
        ko_saved = kmalloc(sizeof(struct kobject_saved), GFP_KERNEL);

        *ko_saved = (struct kobject_saved) {
        .kobj = ko
        };

}
```

Comment: take out the extern in file 1.h and declare in file two .h extern struct *ksaved. extern is to let the compiler know that even though a variable might not have been declared in that file, it is somewhere in another file so it can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elements of the source code are missing to clearly understand what you want to do, for example :

```
struct *ko = ksaved->kobject;
```

can't be right.
I guess you meant :

```
struct kobject* ko = ksaved->kobject;
```

You are basically setting a global variable, which will be modified by two source files. It is not a recommended practice (difficult to maintain).

Anyway, if that's what you want to do, you have to define the global variable in one file, and reference it from the second one, as you did. The `extern` statement would be better remained localized within `file2.c`.

We don't have your exact sequence, so we don't know how your code behaves. Apparently it doesn't crash, so I guess the malloc from `file1.c` has worked correctly. That means that `file1.c` has been run as intended. And it also means that the problem could be this statement :

```
ksaved->kobject = some_kobject; // some_kobject is a initialized pointer to kobj
```

might be wrong : maybe `some_kobject == NULL`;

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I wanted to basically write struct kobject* which I have updated in my question, now. But any help to tell me why pointer goes null will be useful..

Comment: `void save_my_kobject(struct kobject *ko)
{
        ko_saved = kmalloc(sizeof(struct kobject_saved), GFP_KERNEL);
        *ko_saved = (struct kobject_saved) {
        .kobj = ko
        };

}` This is my exact code.

Comment: @paivas Don't post code in comments, edit your question and add relevant information there.

Comment: As a general comment following your update : you are interleaving global variables with local variables into your function code, which makes fairly difficult to follow and debug, even for simple things. 

I would like to invite you to try NOT using global variables, and think your program differently to get rid of them. It will allow you to concentrate your mind in a better direction, with a much safer C code production as a direct consequence.